# ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn), while working with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have trouble querying a table, created with sqlalchemy on postgres db (local).

While I am able to execute, and receive query result with:

```
SELECT * FROM olympic_games
```

I am getting an error message when I'm trying to access single column, or perform any other operation on table:

```
SELECT games FROM olympic_games
```

The error message is (couple sentences translated from Polish):

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) BŁĄD: column "games" does not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(Sport)
>                           ^
>   HINT:  maybe you meant "olympic_games.Games".
>
> SQL: SELECT games FROM olympic_games LIMIT 5;]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

It pretty much sums to that program doesn't see, or can access specific column, and display that it doesn't exist.

I tried accessing with `table.column` format, it didn't work as well. I am also able to see column names, via `information_schema.columns`

Data (.csv) was loaded with `pd.read_csv`, and then `DataFrame.to_sql`. Code below, thanks for help!

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://:@:/olympic_games')

with open('olympic_athletes_2016_14.csv', 'r') as file:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col='ID')
df.to_sql(name = 'olympic_games', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace', index_label = 'ID')
```

Both execute commands returned with same error:

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute("SELECT games FROM olympic_games LIMIT 5;")
    df_fetch = pd.DataFrame(rs.fetchall())
```

```
df_fetch2 = engine.execute("""SELECT games FROM olympic_games LIMIT 5;""").fetchall()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Essentially, this is the double quoting issue of column identifiers as mentioned in the PostgreSQL [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other.

When any of your Pandas data frame columns have mixed cases, the `DataFrame.to_sql` preserves the case sensitivity by creating columns with double quotes at `CREATE TABLE` stage. Specifically, the below Python Pandas code when using *replace*

```
df.to_sql(name='olympic_games', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index_label='ID')
```

Translates as below in Postgres if `Sport` was a titled case column in data frame:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public."olympic_games";

CREATE TABLE public."olympic_games"
(
    ...
    "Sport" varchar(255)
    "Games" varchar(255)
    ...
);
```

Once an identifier is quoted with mixed cases, it must always be referred to in that manner. Therefore `sport` is not the same as `"Sport"`. Remember in SQL, double quotes actually is different than single quotes which can be interchangeable in Python.

To fix, consider rendering all your Pandas columns to lower case since `"games"` is the same as `games`, `Games` or `GAMES` (but not `"Games"` or `"GAMES"`).

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
df.to_sql(name='olympic_games', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index_label='ID')
```

Alternatively, leave as is and quote appropriately:

```sql
SELECT "Games" FROM olympic_games
```

Comment: thank you very much for help, lower cases helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The statement of the database lead me too: `ALTER TABLE public.pages ADD "contentType" varchar(255) NOT NULL;`. It shows the quotation marks. But you have to keep in mind that your query needs to be: `tablename."columnname"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT "games" FROM olympic_games`. In some cases PostgreSQL create the quotes around a columns names. For example if the column name contained mixed register. I have to remind you: PostgreSQL is case sensitive

Comment: PostgreSQL is not case sensitive unless using quoted identidiers, and it does not create quotes around identifiers unless you use them explicitly. `ASDF` is `asdf` is `AsDf`, but none of them are `"ASDF"`. Iirc PostgreSQL deviates from for example Oracle in that the latter folds plain identifiers to uppercase, so all the presented identifiers would match `"ASDF"` in Oracle.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Im missed something about that. Thank you for yours explaining.